# convert very large undirected graph in edgelist form to directed graph in adjlist form

Tags: java, graph

I have a file which has millions of vertices and around billions of edges and its format as edgelist is as follows :

```
7 5
1 2
2 4
2 5
3 6
3 7
```

this graph is undirected however I need to change the graph into directed and adjacency list and weighted (each edge has weight 1) form as follows:

```
7 5
2 1
1 1 4 1 5 1
6 1 7 1
2 1
2 1
3 1
3 1
```

It has a header with the number of vertices and edges. 
I have implemented a code like this using hashmap. However, in very large graphs when the edges exceed billions I get memory exceeding error because of using hashmap. Does anybody have any idea to make this code applicable for any size of graph? 
Here is my code :

```
public class Mygraphgenerator {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String fileName = "test.edgelist";
        String line = null;
        String [] lineSepartor;
        int currentvertice=1;
        int edgecounter=0;
        int vertice;
        int adjacents;
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("test.adjlist"));
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> directedMaker = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String firstline;
            String adjLists="";
            String sentinel=" ";
            boolean f = true;
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                //changeto networkxformat
                //lineSepartor=line.split("\t");
                lineSepartor=line.split(" ");

                vertice=Integer.parseInt(lineSepartor[0]) + 1;
                adjacents=Integer.parseInt(lineSepartor[1]) + 1;

                //if switched from current vertices to the next one (0 to 1)
                if (currentvertice==vertice){
                    if(!f)
                        pw.write(" " + adjacents + " " + "1");

                    else
                    {
                        pw.write(adjacents + " " + "1");

                        f=false;
                    }
                    ArrayList<String> edges;
                    if (directedMaker.containsKey(adjacents)){
                        edges=directedMaker.get(adjacents);
                        edges.add(vertice + "");
                    }else {
                        edges=new ArrayList<String>();
                        edges.add(vertice + "");
                    }
                    directedMaker.put(adjacents,edges);
                    //System.out.println(currentvertice);
                    //System.out.println(adjLists);
                }else {
                    sentinel = "\n";

                    //System.out.println("Insde first while" + currentvertice + " adjLists " + adjLists);
                    pw.write(sentinel);

                    if (vertice -currentvertice>1)
                        for (int i = currentvertice + 1; i < vertice; i++){
                            if (directedMaker.containsKey(i)){
                                f=false;
                                List<String> edges = directedMaker.get(i);
                                for (int j = 0; j< edges.size(); j++){
                                    if(j!=0)
                                        pw.write(" " + edges.get(j) + " " + "1");

                                    else
                                        pw.write(edges.get(j) + " " + "1");

                                }


                                directedMaker.remove(i);
                            }
                            pw.write("\n");
                        }
                    if (directedMaker.containsKey(vertice)){
                        f=false;
                        List<String> edges = directedMaker.get(vertice);
                        for (int i =0; i< edges.size(); i++){
                            if(i!=0)
                                pw.write(" " + edges.get(i) + " " + "1");
                            else
                                pw.write(edges.get(i) + " " + "1");
                        }
                        directedMaker.remove(vertice);
                        pw.write(" " + adjacents + " " + "1");

                    }else
                        pw.write(adjacents + " " + "1");
                    ArrayList<String> edges;
                    if (directedMaker.containsKey(adjacents)){
                        edges=directedMaker.get(adjacents);
                        edges.add(vertice+"");
                    }else {
                        edges=new ArrayList<String>();
                        edges.add(vertice+"");
                    }
                    directedMaker.put(adjacents,edges);
                }
                currentvertice=vertice;
                edgecounter++;
            }
            //System.out.println("In middle " + currentvertice + " adjLists " + adjLists);
            pw.write(adjLists);
            while (directedMaker.size()!=0){
                pw.write("\n");
                currentvertice++;
                //System.out.println("Outside first while " + currentvertice);
                if (directedMaker.containsKey(currentvertice)){
                    List<String> edges = directedMaker.get(currentvertice);
                    for (int i =0; i< edges.size(); i++){
                        if(i!=0)
                            pw.write(" " + edges.get(i) + " " + "1");
                        else
                            pw.write(edges.get(i) + " " + "1");
                    }
                    directedMaker.remove(currentvertice);
                }
            }
            pw.close();
            System.out.println("done!"); 
            System.out.println("edges of this graph : " + edgecounter);
        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(
                    "Unable to open file '" + 
                            fileName + "'");                
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If database storage is not an option then perhaps each key could instead be a temporary file, appending to the relevant temp file as the input file is processed.  At the end, merge all the temp files.

Comment: I do not clearly understand what do you suggest. Do you mean that I write key of hashmap into a temporary file?

Comment: A map would not be used at all.  What would have been the key to the map would be a temporary file: fileName = adjacents + ".tmp".